# What effect does Baking Soda and Citric Acid have on a soft drink?

Tags: acid-base

In chemistry, we are doing a project where we have to make our own carbonated soda. The ingredients our group is using are:

1. Baking Soda ($\ce{ NaHCO3}$)
2. Citric Acid ($\ce{C6H8O7}$)
3. Flavoring powder (ex. KoolAid flavoring
       powder)
4. Sugar
5. Water

Using stoichiometry, our group has already calculated how much citric acid we need based on the **1 gram of baking soda** that we are deciding to putting in: we have to use **0.76 g citric acid** based on our calculations.

My question is, what effect does baking soda have and what effect does citric acid have on the soda? Does baking soda make it "bubbly"? Does citric acid make it more concentrated?

Comment: Hint: the "bubbly" part of a carbonated beverage is the carbonation - dissolved $\ce{CO2}$. What happens when baking soda reacts with acid? What is your acid?

Answer (score 3):

Actually if we care just about the reaction between Baking Soda ($\ce{NaHCO3}$) and Citric Acid ($\ce{C6H8O7}$) the following reaction should ensure :

$$\ce{3NaHCO3(aq) + C6H8O7(aq) -> 3 H2O (l) + 3 CO2(g) + Na3C6H5O7(aq)}$$

So basically the reaction should produce water, carbon dioxide and trisodium citrate (as known as E331 : a food additive)